# Error in Xcode console: "void * _Nullable NSMapGet(NSMapTable * _Nonnull, const void * _Nullable): map table argument is NULL"

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

When running my iOs app on either a physical device or in simulator, I am getting the following error in Xcode console:

```
void * _Nullable NSMapGet(NSMapTable * _Nonnull, const void * _Nullable): map table argument is NULL
```

How can I identify which parts of the code produce this error?

After launch, the app seems a bit stuck - i.e. a textView in my interface gets "frozen" at app start, then the above error message is printed in console, then the caret in the textView comes alive - i.e. starts blinking as it is supposed to do). The "freeze" takes about 2-3 seconds then the app performs ok.

Update 1: I tried adding a breakpoint, but nothing happens in the console:
[screenshot of the breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53JiK.png)

Update 2: After more investigation I see that if I delete in viewDidLoad(): `textView.becomeFirstResponder()` the error is no longer printed in console. Stil, I am not sure why the error is present if I set the textView as firstResponder in viewDidLoad().

Comment: Use the debugger, set a breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you, I just did, with no result (I updated the initial post with a screenshot).